# Having problems w/ recursion in binary search tree algorithm

Tags: python

I am having problems while trying to write a recursive pre-order algorithm in python. It is saying that my `preOrder` function is not defined.

```
NameError: name 'preOrder' is not defined
```

---

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
    def preOrder(key):
        if key:
            print(key.val)
            preOrder(key.left)
            preOrder(key.right)

root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.left = Node(6)
root.right.right = Node(7)
root.preOrder()
```

I am running Windows and using Atom Text Editor.

Comment: Do you want `preOrder` to be a static method in which case you should add that as a decorator and call it like `Node.preOrder(node_instance)` or a regular method which you would call like you are doing now (but the function would need to take in `self`)?

Comment: I would just keep it a regular method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Option 1

If you want `preOrder` to be a seperate static method, you could simply deindent your code to:

```py
class Node():
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

def preOrder(key):
    if key:
        print(key.val)
        preOrder(key.left)
        preOrder(key.right)

root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.left = Node(6)
root.right.right = Node(7)
preOrder(root)
```

Because this is now a static method, notice how the last line also changed

## Option 2

You could make preOrder a static class method, like this:

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

    @staticmethod
    def preOrder(key):
        if key:
            print(key.val)
            Node.preOrder(key.left)
            Node.preOrder(key.right)

root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.left = Node(6)
root.right.right = Node(7)
Node.preOrder(root)
```

Notice how now you need to call `Node.preOrder`

## Option 3

We can make it a method of each class, like this:

```py
class Node():
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

    def preOrder(self):
        print(self.val)
        if self.left:
            self.left.preOrder()
        if self.right:
            self.right.preOrder()

root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.left = Node(6)
root.right.right = Node(7)
root.preOrder()
```

This is the only way to keep your original syntax for calls. Notice how the function arguments changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Node():
def __init__(self,val):
    self.val = val
    self.right = None
    self.left = None

def preOrder(self, key):
    if key:
        print(key.val)
        self.preOrder(key.left)
        self.preOrder(key.right)


root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.left = Node(6)
root.right.right = Node(7)
root.preOrder()
```

You also need to pass an argument to the preOrder() method on the last line.